# wifi adapter not found

Tags: networking, oracle-linux

I have been using oracle 9.2 for one year, no issue with network at all.

Yesterday the system crashed badly and self restarted; at restart the wifi adapter had simply disappear, on settings menu the wifi wasn't listed anymore.

on running lspci:

```
[root@192 xxx.yyy] $ lspci | grep Network
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake PCH CNVi WiFi (rev 11)

[root@192 xxx.yyy]# rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
[root@192 xxx.yyy]# lshw -c network
  *-network:0 UNCLAIMED     
       description: Network controller
       product: Tiger Lake PCH CNVi WiFi
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       version: 11
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff memory:6053b9c000-6053b9ffff
  *-network:1
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (14) I219-V
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: enp0s31f6
       version: 11
       serial: 5c:60:ba:48:57:50
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=5.15.0-200.131.27.el9uek.x86_64 firmware=0.4-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:170 memory:6ec80000-6ec9ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: SAMSUNG_Android
       physical id: 10
       bus info: usb@3:1
       logical name: enp0s20f0u1
       serial: 66:62:d1:cf:f9:16
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=5.15.0-200.131.27.el9uek.x86_64 duplex=half firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.233.158 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair
[root@192 xxx.yyy]# lspci -knn | grep -A 2 -i net
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake PCH CNVi WiFi [8086:43f0] (rev 11)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX201 160MHz [8086:0074]
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
--
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (14) I219-V [8086:15fa] (rev 11)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8870]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
[root@192 xxx.yyy]#
```

Where is the issue?

I have also a windows os on the same machine and it works fine

why is network 0 UNCLAIMED ? what dozs it it mean?

---

errors that I found on start up logs, it is not clear to me if they are relevant or not:

```
Dec 10 10:57:26 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[54089]: <info>  [1702202246.7101] NetworkManager (version 1.42.2-8.0.1.el9_2) is starting... (after a restart, boot:9e78d0ab-6976-4743-bfe2-f286efbe4a12)
Dec 10 10:57:26 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[54089]: <info>  [1702202246.7102] Read config: /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf (lib: 00-server.conf, 10-disable-mptcp.conf) (run: 15-carrier-timeout.conf)
Dec 10 10:57:26 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[54089]: <error> [1702202246.7115] bus-manager: fatal failure to acquire D-Bus service "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager" (3). Service already taken
Dec 10 10:57:26 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[54089]: <info>  [1702202246.7115] exiting (error)
Dec 10 10:57:46 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[54103]: <info>  [1702202266.7479] NetworkManager (version 1.42.2-8.0.1.el9_2) is starting... (after a restart, boot:9e78d0ab-6976-4743-bfe2-f286efbe4a12)
Dec 10 10:57:46 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[54103]: <info>  [1702202266.7480] Read config: /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf (lib: 00-server.conf, 10-disable-mptcp.conf) (run: 15-carrier-timeout.conf)
Dec 10 10:57:46 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[54103]: <error> [1702202266.7487] bus-manager: fatal failure to acquire D-Bus service "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager" (3). Service already taken
Dec 10 10:57:46 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[54103]: <info>  [1702202266.7488] exiting (error)
```

---

```
[root@192 system-connections]# rpm -Vf /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/net/wireless/*80211.ko*
.M.......  g /boot/System.map-5.15.0-200.131.27.el9uek.x86_64
.M.......  g /boot/initramfs-5.15.0-200.131.27.el9uek.x86_64.img
.M.......  g /boot/System.map-5.15.0-200.131.27.el9uek.x86_64
.M.......  g /boot/initramfs-5.15.0-200.131.27.el9uek.x86_64.img
[root@192 system-connections]# rpm -Vf /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko*
.M.......  g /boot/System.map-5.15.0-200.131.27.el9uek.x86_64
.M.......  g /boot/initramfs-5.15.0-200.131.27.el9uek.x86_64.img
[root@192 system-connections]#
```

---

```
[root@192 system-connections]# dmesg | grep 0000:00:14.3
[    3.731567] pci 0000:00:14.3: [8086:43f0] type 00 class 0x028000
[    3.731586] pci 0000:00:14.3: reg 0x10: [mem 0x6053b9c000-0x6053b9ffff 64bit]
[    3.731700] pci 0000:00:14.3: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
[    3.800182] pci 0000:00:14.3: Adding to iommu group 11
```

Comment: Look at your system startup log (watch your kernel discover the hardware) with the terminal command `sudo journalctl  -b 0`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: I added some lines of logs that maybe are relevant. Something of specific to search from the logs?

Comment: Try to downgrade the networkmanager version. Some NM bugs cause the system crash

Answer (score 0):

`UNCLAIMED` in the `lshw` output means "the kernel failed to find a suitable driver for this device, or loading the driver failed". As mentioned by waltinator, the startup log viewable by `sudo journalctl -b 0` might have a more detailed error message.

After a crash, it might be possible that the WiFi chip was left in some error state and the driver doesn't know how to clear it. In such a case, fully powering down the system and restarting will usually help. But if you rebooted into Windows, and the WiFi chip worked with it, then rebooted into Linux again, and the WiFi still did not work, then this is not a transient problem that could be fixed with a power cycle.

Because the device used to work before, and still works with Windows, that might mean either the driver, or the firmware file required by the driver, could be damaged.

The Linux driver for the Intel AX201 WiFi chip has several parts:

- the `iwlwifi` kernel module, located at `/lib/modules/<kernel version>/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko`
- the `iwlmvm` sub-module, located at `/lib/modules/<kernel version>/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/mvm/iwlmvm.ko`
- the firmware file(s), located at `/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-*.ucode` (there might be multiple firmware versions available; each driver will usually prefer the newest firmware version that was available at the kernel release time, but can fall back to older firmware versions if necessary)

To verify the health of the driver files, you could use the *verify* function of the `rpm` command:

```
sudo rpm -Vf /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko*
sudo rpm -Vf /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/mvm/iwlmvm.ko*
sudo rpm -Vf /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-Qu-*.ucode.xz
```

If there is no output from the `rpm -Vf` command, it means the file is exactly as it was when it was installed from the corresponding RPM package and should be OK.

An error message will probably mean the file is missing; a string of 9 letters/numbers/dots followed by the file pathname indicates the file has been modified or damaged in some way. See `man rpm` for the exact meaning of each letter in the verification result, if you're interested.

If either of the kernel module files is missing or damaged, you'll need to reinstall the corresponding kernel module RPM file for your current kernel:

```
sudo dnf reinstall kernel-modules-$(uname -r)
```

If the firmware files are damaged or missing, you'll need to reinstall the corresponding firmware RPM, which is named `iwl7260-firmware` in this case:

```
sudo dnf reinstall iwl7260-firmware
```

After reinstalling the damaged files, you could try reloading the driver:

```
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi   # unload the driver if it's loaded
sudo modprobe iwlwifi      # reload it
```

The errors you found in the startup logs:

```
bus-manager: fatal failure to acquire D-Bus service "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager" (3). Service already taken
```

suggest that an instance of NetworkManager is trying to start when there already appears to be another instance of it running. Maybe the first instance started before the WiFi driver module was loaded, and is somehow hung up in trying to detect the WiFi card?

You might want to verify NetworkManager is undamaged (`sudo rpm -V NetworkManager`), and try restarting it (`systemctl restart NetworkManager.service`).

If that turns out to be helpful, it might be necessary to add a custom dependency to NetworkManager that prevents it from starting until the WiFi device is fully ready.

And one more sanity check: does your system have a physical switch for "airplane mode", i.e. for disabling all radio transmitters? If your system has one, make sure it's in the *enabled* position.

Comment: the rpm -Vf didn't return nothing for the 3 modules/firmwares; are there others modules that need a verify? how can I check that the modules/firmware are loaded?  running "modprobe -c" I can see several alias with "iwlwifi" but not with "iwlmvm"; is it normal?

Comment: Use `lsmod` to see if the kernel modules are loaded or not; if you have recently booted the system or reloaded the driver, there should be messages in the `sudo dmesg` output about it (try `sudo dmesg |grep iwl`). One of those messages should say something like `iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version ...` if the firmware was successfully loaded. And yes, the large number of `alias pci:...` lines for iwlwifi and none for iwlmvm is normal: iwlwifi is normally loaded by PCI(e) auto-detection, and once it's identified the chip type, it will load the iwlmvm module by name, no alias needed.

Comment: 'lsmod' and 'dmesg' don't return any line that contain "iwl"

Comment: So the module is not loaded. Run `sudo modprobe iwlwifi`, then `sudo dmesg |grep iwl` again. Any new messages?

Comment: why `modprobe -v  iwlwifi` - `insmod /lib/modules/5.15.0-200.131.27.el9uek.x86_64/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko.xz` - `modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'iwlwifi': Invalid argument` ?

Comment: `cfg80211.ko.xz` is the module for the wireless interface configuration subsystem. Let's verify the subsystem modules too: `sudo rpm -Vf /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/net/wireless/*80211.ko*` and `sudo rpm -Vf /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko*`. Also, did the modprobe attempt produce any new messages to the tail end of the `dmesg` output?

Comment: I added the output of rpm command on the description; about dmesg: it looks like the same of before (there are some errors, as before, apparently not releted to the issue, I can append all it on the description if you want)

Comment: If something new was added to the `dmesg` listing when you attempted `modprobe -v iwlwifi`, then please append the added lines only. The whole of the `dmesg` output is quite long, and typically contains much that is not relevant to the issue; but anything related to the wireless subsystem or to the PCI(e) device `0000:00:14.3` could be important.

Comment: ok, I did a compare and yes there are several new lines (I will add them upper); some of the lines are about samsung usb device (I'm using the tethering throught the mobile phone) but I didn't see nothing releated to network

Comment: I added only the lines about `0000:00:14.3`; but nothing is changed after the run of modprobe